# MatLab - accessing subfolders of folders saved as variables

Tags: matlab, subdirectory

I have the following code which can create a directory within a selected folder:

```
photos_dir = 'C:\Users\Bob\Photos';

mkdir(photos_dir,'Christmas 2015')
```

I'd like to then be able to save an image to this folder, I think using something like:

```
imwrite(img,Christmas 2015,'jpg')
```

However, this does not select the "Christmas 2015" folder which is in the "\Photos" directory. How can I make the image be written to this location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're going to have a syntax error since `Christmas 2015` should at least be a string. But other than that, if you want to save a file in a particular location (other than the current working directory), you need to provide the *full path* to the file location.

To do this, you need to use [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to combine all of your directory and file names together into a full file path.

```
image_name = fullfile(photos_dir, 'Christmas 2015', 'yourphoto.jpg');

imwrite(img, image_name, 'jpg')
```